# GARCH(1,2) with $\beta_1=0$?

Tags: matlab, garch

I have a question regarding GARCH(1,2)  estimation. I used Matlab econometrics toolbox to estimate a GARCH(1,2) model. A likelihood ratio test suggested that it would be a better fit than GARCH(1,1), GARCH(2,1) or GARCH(2,2).

Now my `b1` coefficient for the first lag is equal to zero. Is this possible?

My code:

```
pd4 = fitdist(res3,'tLocationScale');
v4= ceil(pd4.ParameterValues(1,3));
tdist4=struct('Name','t','DoF',v4);

Mdl4=garch('Offset',0,'GARCHLags',2,'ARCHLags',1,'Distribution',tdist4);
[EstMdl4,EstParamCov4,logL4,info4]=estimate(Mdl4,res4);
```

Comment: in addition, none of my time series with standartized residuals are standard normal distributed. But a test for arch effects as well as a lbq test on squared residuals show no evidence for autocorrelation or arch effect...

Comment: I cannot read MatLab code so I will not comment on that. Do you assume the standardized residuals to be normally distributed? I see some trace of $t$-distribution in your code, but I cannot follow that entirely. In case you assume a $t$-distribution, you would want the normalized residuals to be $t$-distributed rather than normal. Regarding  the first lag having a zero coefficient, I do not see a big problem there. Technically it is possible; meanwhile, interpretation is not too important in a reduced form model such as GARCH (or ARIMA). By the way, you could include the output of the code.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a problem there. Technically you may have GARCH(1,2) with the coefficient on $\sigma_{t-1}^2$ being equal to zero (similarly, there is nothing wrong with ARMA models that have some zero coefficients). It is a matter of how well the model approximates the data, and apparently GARCH(1,2) does a better job that its competitors for your data.